# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5472 error when populating textview inside tablerow

Tags: android, fatal-error, sigabrt

I'm trying to populate textview inside tablerow but keep getting this error. I've tried with less than 4 textview inside row2 and it is working but more than 4 textview will throw the error.

Layout:

```
           <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableLayout
                     android:id="@+id/stocklist"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:clickable="true"/>
            </ScrollView>


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/stockinfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </ScrollView>
```

Code:

```
        TableLayout stcktable = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.stockinfo);
        for(int i=0;i < contacts.size();i++) {
            try {
                TableRow row=new TableRow(getActivity());
                TextView tvDebt=new TextView(getActivity());
                tvDebt.setText(contacts.get(i).getStockname());
                tvDebt.setTextSize(12);
                if (contacts.get(i).getStockStatus().equals("up")) {
                    tvDebt.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.textGreen));
                } else if (contacts.get(i).getStockStatus().equals("down")) {
                    tvDebt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } else if (contacts.get(i).getStockStatus().equals("nochange")) {
                    tvDebt.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                tvDebt.setTypeface(ApplicationGlobles.roboto(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext()));
                tvDebt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                tvDebt.setPadding(25, 0, 0, 0);
                tvDebt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        0, // TODO width
                        100,1f));
                row.addView(tvDebt);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                       TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // TODO width
                       TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); // height);
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                stcktable.addView(row);
                tvDebt=null;
                System.gc();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            TableRow row2 = new TableRow(getActivity());
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                try {
                    TextView tv1=new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(contacts.get(i).getPrice()));
                    tv1.setTextSize(10);
                    tv1.setTypeface(ApplicationGlobles.roboto(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext()));
                    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv1.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
                    tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            0, // TODO width
                            100,1f));
                    tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape2);
                    row2.addView(tv1);

                    tv1 = null;
                    System.gc();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            row2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // TODO width
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); // height);
            table.addView(row2);
        }
```

Error:

```
03-21 19:16:18.216: A/libc(5472): new failed to allocate 65536 bytes
03-21 19:16:18.226: A/libc(5472): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5472 (sa.market.place)
```